# Preg_match for counting uppercase and circumflex characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regex to count characters in a string which need 2 keystrokes to create the character. I started out quite simple, just counting uppercase characters:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $string, $matches);
```

Now I also want to find circumflexed characters: **â ê î û ô**

Just adding these in the regex doesn't seem to work, at least I receive some weird results:

```
$string = 'Têst';
echo preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $string, $matches);
```

will echo "1", which is fine.

```
$string = 'Têst';
echo preg_match_all('/[A-Zê]/', $string, $treffer);
```

will echo "3", which is weird.

Comment: have you not tried to search for only circumflexed characters? they might enter the match as two characters (representing the two keystrokes, and thus giving you a count of two for each character). Unless there's some mysterious unicode mode that interprets them as a single character, you could run two regexes, one for Caps and one for circumflexed characters, then divide the count of circumflexed chars by two before adding? this seems obvious, but I have no way of knowing what your other requirements are, much less your level of experience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), otherwise "ê" is considered as having 2 chars (2 bytes):

```
$string = 'Têst';
echo preg_match_all('/[A-Zê]/u', $string, $treffer); // 2
```

Demo @ [IDEOne.com](http://ideone.com/wUpfA).

Comment: Perfect, and also thank you for letting me know about IDEOne.com

Answer (score 0):

When I matched `'/[A-Zê]/'` against `'Têst'`, I got 2 results. (which is what you expect). My source code is encoded with charset UTF-8, maybe a different charset could be the reason why you have a different result. Also, you can `print_r($matches);` to have a better idea of what is being matched.

This example worked fine for me: (IDE: netbeans, platform: windows, php version: 5.3.4)

```
<?php
$string = 'Täst';
echo preg_match_all('/[A-Zâêîûôäëïöü]/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Interestingly, ideone also give you 3 results for the first test, and i don't know why. In addition, it is pretty hard to debug because ideone doesn't output var_dump or print_r properly for some reason...
http://ideone.com/qqQyA